# SQL Time Avg Calculation

Tags: postgresql

In my table, I'm storing `action_seconds` for any event in seconds

Table Name: `event_table`

```
id | action_seconds
1  | 90
2  | 120
3  | 140
```

Now, when I calculate avg of action_seconds,

Query: `select avg(action_seconds) from event_table;`

**Expected Output**: 1.56

**Actual Output**: 116.66

Is it possible? how to do? what kind of casting I have to implement to achieve this expected result?

Comment: hey, it would be helpful to know the exact data type definition of the column action_seconds...

Comment: by defining action_seconds as interval, I get an average of 1 min 56.6667 seconds. this actually matches 116.66 seconds...

Comment: data type of action_seconds is integer. Redshift doesnt support interval data type!

Comment: [link] (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html)

Comment: The average of the data can be calculated by hand `(90+120+14)/3` and the result is `116.66666666666667`. Why do you expect the value is `1.56`?

Comment: 116.67 seconds = 1 minute 56 seconds = 1.94 minutes (116.67/60). Take FLOOR(116.67/60) = 1 minute and 116 % 60 = 56 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query. This will return the average (which was in seconds originally) as minutes.seconds

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((AVG(action_seconds) || ' second')::interval, 'MI.SS') FROM event_table;
```